# Web Config changes for deployment slots in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have created 3 deployment slots on my Azure Website.

1. DevTest
2. QA
3. Staging

For each slot I need to customize the web.config file.  The changes are through out the web.config file and not only in the AppSettings and ConnectionString sections, such as web service endpoints, smtp details, logging details, debugging details, etc...

It seems as though Azure only supports changes in the ConnectionString and the AppSettings.

How do I configure these different slots to update the rest of the web.config?

The end result would be that I would like to continuously integrate to DevTest, then swap that into QA, Staging and finally into Production.  I have tried release management but this seems to only support Azure VM deployments.  I am a noob at powershell which I believe may be the answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

====== RESOLUTION ======

So, I thought I'd feedback on this for anyone else that is looking for a way to do this.  Basically I created a WebConfig.cs class as follows:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebConfig), "PopulateFromAppSettings")]
namespace Application.Presentation.Web
{
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Xml;

    public static class WebConfig
    {
        private static XmlDocument webConfig;

        private static bool docChanged = false;

        public static bool isConfigured = false;

        static WebConfig()
        {
            if (isConfigured)
            {
                return;
            }

            webConfig = new XmlDocument();
            webConfig.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        }

        public static void PopulateFromAppSettings()
        {
            if (isConfigured)
            {
                return;
            }

            // system.web
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.web/compilation", "debug", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["compilationDebug"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.web/customErrors", "mode", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["customErrorsMode"]);

            // log4net
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/log4net/appender/param[@name='ConnectionString']", "value", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureAppenderConnectionString"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/log4net/appender/param[@name='ContainerName']", "value", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureAppenderConnectionString"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/log4net/appender/param[@name='DirectoryName']", "value", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureAppenderConnectionString"]);

            // system.identityModel
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration/issuerNameRegistry/trustedIssuers/add", "name", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuerNameRegistryTrustedIssuers"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration/issuerNameRegistry/trustedIssuers/add", "thumbprint", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["trustedIssuersThumbprint"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration/audienceUris/add", "value", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["audienceUriValue"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel.services/federationConfiguration/wsFederation", "issuer", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederationIssuer"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel.services/federationConfiguration/wsFederation", "realm", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederationRealm"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel.services/federationConfiguration/wsFederation", "reply", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederationReply"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration/certificateValidation", "certificateValidationMode", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificateValidationMode"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration/certificateValidation", "revocationMode", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificateRevocationMode"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration/certificateValidation", "trustedStoreLocation", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificateTrustedStoreLocation"]);

            // system.serviceModel
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint", "address", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpointAddress"]);
            SetAttributeValue("/configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint/identity/servicePrincipalName", "value", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servicePrincipalName"]);

            if (docChanged)
            {
                webConfig.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
            }

            isConfigured = true;
        }

        private static void SetAttributeValue(string xpath, string attributeName, string value)
        {
            var selectSingleNode = webConfig.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
            if (selectSingleNode != null && selectSingleNode.Attributes != null)
            {
                if (selectSingleNode.Attributes[attributeName].Value != value)
                {
                    selectSingleNode.Attributes[attributeName].Value = value;
                    docChanged = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Config attribute '{0}' was not found in config at path '{1}'", attributeName, xpath));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code is what causes the method to be run at startup.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebConfig), "PopulateFromAppSettings")]
```

I created all the variables in my Web.Config->AppSettings and then created them under Azure -> Application Settings.

It seems to work well except for one problem.  The update code only executes when the website is run the first time.  Which means for the first execution, the settings are all wrong.  When I reload the website, the new settings take effect.  A small price to pay I think.  I will post back if I figure out any better ways of doing this.

Comment: So do you expect QA settings to be moved to Staging and then to Production? Because that's how slots work in Azure WebSites.

Comment: @trailmax no, they wouldn't be moved. You can set whether a setting is specific to a slot or not.  So I would just mark the relevant settings.

Comment: Yes, that applies to AppSettings and connection strings, but the rest of `web.config` will move. I think you need OctopusDeploy to do deployments for you - it can do `web.config` transforms depending on the deployment parameters.

Comment: @trailmax I see what you're saying, this is the crux of my question. I need a way to have all those settings static for my slots. I had a look at OctopusDeploy and found the pricing rather expensive. No doubt it's worth it, but in a small company with a small team I can hardly justify it.

Comment: I think you'll find "keep web.config per slot" rather difficult to achieve. Bear in mind that Octopus is offered for free for small teams with under 5 projects.

Comment: Also I'm configuring my logging and SMTP and other stuff through `appSettings`. I had to dance a bit around NLog, but can be done. SMTP config through `appSettings` was simple. I'm sure other stuff can be re-configured in the similar matter. Probably this will be easier than trying to bend AWS into submission.

Comment: @trailmax I am current exploring another option with MS Release Management that uses a "jump box" which is a temp VM to achieve the deployments.  The problem with the free OctopusDeploy was the project limit, other than that it would have been awesome.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever find anyway better of doing this?  Almost 4 years later and they seem to have not moved any closer to a better solution.

Comment: @Hobbes, I actually ended up moving to Octopus Deploy.  I've since then moved on so haven't pursued this any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell is not quite the answer here, PowerShell is just one client to surface Azure App Service platform functionality. web.config is considered content from deployment slot perspective and thus it is not swap invariant. One option to consider would be surfacing the settings that require customization as app settings (environment variables) and populating them across all the slots. At runtime you can detect which slot the code is running in/which settings should be used by reading the Azure App Service populated WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME app setting.

Comment: Just to clarrify, are you suggesting that I move all the settings into AppSettings and then using code to set up the various sections in something like the AppStart method? I guess that's probably the best answer.

Comment: Yes, that was the suggestion.

Comment: So this is the answer I am marking as correct as it is the way I'm going.  I am struggling with some of the changes but i think I will get through it. I need to figure out how to make sure the changes only occur once after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for Visual Studio called [slow cheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5), which allows you to make transforms of your Web.config using XDT which will allow you to transform any section of your Web.config file.

The only issue is that this solution works best with Web Deploy as the transformation is done on build and the bits for slow cheetah are not available on Azure Web App.

Comment: You don't need Slow Cheetah for `web.config`. You need this extension for non-web stuff. For some reason MS does not offer config transformation for non-web projects, hence Slow Cheetah was created.

Comment: Point #6 on the description page:

Comment: Wanted to transform files in addition to web.config on publish for Web projects

Comment: I have used Slow Cheetah before to transform app.config for console applications.  However, using transforms puts production information in the hands of developers, so I don't like them for team development.